# Problem with lstrip and backslash in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, backslash

I know there is already many ressources about the problem of backslash in python, I read many of these but none help me.

I'm working on large data set with Pandas.

I'm creating a loop to iterate over multiple csv files in a windows folder. Then it proceed to several data manipulation. Then I want to save each different input csv in different output csv.

In itself, it works, but I want to have clean name after the export/save. And i'm not able to do this.

Complete name are "C:\blabla blabla\data number1\Id 1\Csv\01 - Decembre\12-xx-14_processed_1.csv"

xx = multiple day of the month

Here's the code :

```
    for files in folder :
            df = pd.read_csv(files, sep=';', low_memory=False, index_col=None)
            file_name = str(files)
            file_name = file_name.lstrip(r'C:\blabla blabla\data number1\Id 1\Csv\01 - Decembre\\')
            file_name = file_name.rstrip('_processed_1.csv')
```

I want to have only "12-xx-14.csv" in the end

So I did the following :

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\blabla blabla\data number1\Reprocessed CSV\December'+str(file_name)+'.csv',index=False)
```

Saving it in another folder for the project management.

I should have "12-xx-14.csv" as an output.. but I have "2-xx-14.csv" ! My first "1" is going into the bin and I really don't know why ??
I guess it's related to the backslash character.. But if i'm deleting the last two backslash, the name become "01 - December\12-xx-14". I can't even manage to suppress "01 - Decembe" without the last "r", it won't work.

I'm currently upgrading to python 3.9 to test suffix/prefix, but in the mean time i'm stuck with this.

Thank you !

Comment: You're stripping away the "1" and then wonder why it's not there anymore?

Comment: Well, the "1" should not be removed by my code, and that's the problem.. :( Maybe you see something I don't ?

Comment: Well you explicitly include "1" in the set of characters to strip away. Even *twice*!

Comment: Oh gosh you mean, if I put a 1 in the lstrip it will remove ALL the 1 character ??

I was thinking that it needed an exact match to remove.. Like "lstrip(apple)" would only remove the word apple and not every "a"p"l"e"

Comment: It'll remove all the ones it gets to. Is [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) with its examples not clear?

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround to solve that particular problem with backslash:

```
file_name = str(r"C:\blabla blabla\data number1\Id 1\Csv\01 - Decembre\12-xx-14_processed_1.csv")
print('1',file_name)
file_name = file_name.replace("\\", "^")
print('2',file_name)
file_name = file_name.replace("C:^blabla blabla^data number1^Id 1^Csv^01 - Decembre^","")
print('3',file_name)
file_name = file_name.replace("_processed_1.csv","")
print('4',file_name)
```

Output:

```
1 C:\blabla blabla\data number1\Id 1\Csv\01 - Decembre\12-xx-14_processed_1.csv
2 C:^blabla blabla^data number1^Id 1^Csv^01 - Decembre^12-xx-14_processed_1.csv
3 12-xx-14_processed_1.csv
4 12-xx-14
```

---edit---

```
a = r"C:\blabla blabla\data number1\Id 1\Csv\01 - Decembre\12-xx-14_processed_1.csv"
print('5',a)
a = a[53:61]+a[73:79]
print('6',a)
```

Output:

```
5 C:\\blabla blabla\\data number1\\Id 1\\Csv\\01 - Decembre\\12-xx-14_processed_1.csv
6 12-xx-14.csv
```

Definitely a cleaner version

Comment: Oh that's very smart !! 
Well, I proceed with another strange way that finally work : 
        file_name = str(files)
        file_name = file_name.lstrip('C:\blabla blabla\data number1\Id 1\Csv\01 - Decembre')
        file_name = file_name.rstrip('_processed_1.csv')
        file_name = file_name.lstrip('01 - Decembre')
        file_name = file_name + ".csv"
It works.. but it's not very "clean" as solution.

I will consider doing some replace with these backslash character, that's for sure a very good way to deal with it ! Thanks :)

Comment: I always do this kind of replace every time backslash comes into play. It's very convenient. Other possible workaround is to take the string as it is and do numpy slicing. The prefix and sufix are always the same anyway, right?

Comment: I submitted an edit with another approach